# Request is blank when sending data through iOS to google cloud endpoint

Tags: ios, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

i am working on Google cloud endpoint with datastore. When i am passing data through Android & iOS with method POST , it is getting saved in datastore with empty record. i.e. request is properly working but the way  i am sending data is wrong. please help me for this.
For iOS, code is mentioned below :

```
NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"application/json",
                           @"cache-control": @"no-cache",
                           @"postman-token": @"404012ff-722e-c5d8-48db-fa7fb3260841"};
NSLog(@"header %@",headers);
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"enter url here..."]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];
NSString*  strRequest=@"";
strRequest =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"displayEmail=%@&displayName=%@",@"sonal@gmail.com",@"sonal"];
NSLog(@"url is %@  parameter = %@", request , strRequest);
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: [strRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                NSLog(@"responce Body===>%@",responseBody);
                                                if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                } else {
                                                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                    NSLog(@"responce%@", httpResponse);
                                                }
                                            }];
[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: How do you find out the request is blank? We need some more code.

Comment: i edited my code..please have a look and let me know

Comment: The code looks right. But how are telling that the request is blank.

Comment: we got a solution..we changed the way of passing data..                   here is code :                                                                               `request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:syncURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];
  NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[serverSyncAPIRequestJSON UTF8String] length:[serverSyncAPIRequestJSON length]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

Comment: You should post this one as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `httpBody` property of your request. If you don't provide a body for the POST, of **course** it's blank.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1409064-httpbody

Or Objective-C

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1409064-httpbody?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

We got a solution..
we changed the way of passing data.. 
here is code :

```
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:syncURL] 
       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];
       NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[serverSyncAPIRequestJSON UTF8String] length:[serverSyncAPIRequestJSON length]];[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; [request setHTTPBody:requestData]; [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```